# How do I get the Access-Token and Access-Token-Secret?

Tags: java, security, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Can anyone explain me these terms with respect to OAuth ?

```
Consumer Key 
Consumer Secret
Access Token
Access Token Secret
```

Also, when I registered my application with twitter I got the *consumer key* and *consumer secret* but how do I get the *access token* and *access token secret* ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Twitter Application Management Page](https://apps.twitter.com/) - Select the App which you have created - Click `API Keys` Tab.

[image]

Now, Click `Create My Access Token` to generate

- Access Token and
- Access Token Secret.

[image]